# How to parse on google reader?

Tags: parsing

I want to parse News article.
So, I want to use google reader parse.

I use httpclient.jar file.
To parse, I used GetMethod to get Auth_Token.

but i can't get auth token

Answer (score 1):

You need to study the Google Auth APIs.  Try this page: https://developers.google.com/accounts/.